# Synology blue led of death (led blinking)

Tags: raid, raid5, synology, dsm

My Synology (10 disks) suddenly doesn't reboot.

Connecting it with the serial port, I could manage to boot on "Synology 1" and "Synology 2"

Synology 1, is a kind of "recovery partition" allowing you to recover your DSM with the synology assistant.

Synology 2, is the default boot option and boots on your DSM. In my case, the synology server fails to boot.

I've an raid 5 of 10 disks.

How to recover it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution this way.

I removed ALL the disks an formated one of the disk (you'd better use a new one. I had a backup so didn't take much risk doing this) using

- parted
- mklabel gpt
- write
- quit

I inserted this only disk in the last slot of my synology server. and rebooted it. 
At this moment synology assistant was able to install a new dsm version.

After installation of the dsm , I choose not to configure a raid.([https://www.synology.com/en-us/knowledgebase/DSM/tutorial/General/How_to_reset_your_Synology_NAS]) reboot the synology.

Once rebooted, I added the 9 old other disks and connected with ssh to my synology.

Find out raid information on your disks

```
bash-4.3# mdadm --examine /dev/sd[a-z] 
mdadm: No md superblock detected on /dev/sda.
mdadm: No md superblock detected on /dev/sdb.
mdadm: No md superblock detected on /dev/sdc.
mdadm: No md superblock detected on /dev/sdd.
mdadm: No md superblock detected on /dev/sde.
mdadm: No md superblock detected on /dev/sdf.
mdadm: No md superblock detected on /dev/sdg.
mdadm: No md superblock detected on /dev/sdh.
mdadm: No md superblock detected on /dev/sdi.
mdadm: No md superblock detected on /dev/sdj
```

Those are the raid configured by the DSM so, didn't find anything on my disks

```
bash-4.3# cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : [linear] [raid0] [raid1] [raid10] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] 
md1 : active raid1 sdj2[0]
      2097088 blocks [10/1] [U_________]

md0 : active raid1 sdj1[0]
      2490176 blocks [10/1] [U_________]
```

Trying to assemble raids with scan option

```
bash-4.3# mdadm --assemble --scan
```

Seems to work !

```
bash-4.3# cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : [linear] [raid0] [raid1] [raid10] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] 
md125 : active raid1 sda1[0] sdi1[8] sdh1[7] sdg1[6] sdf1[5] sde1[4] sdd1[3] sdc1[2] sdb1[1]
      2490176 blocks [10/9] [UUUUUUUUU_]

md126 : active raid1 sda2[0] sdi2[8] sdh2[7] sdg2[6] sdf2[5] sde2[4] sdd2[3] sdc2[2] sdb2[1]
      2097088 blocks [10/9] [UUUUUUUUU_]

md127 : active raid5 sda5[0] sdi5[8] sdh5[7] sdg5[6] sdf5[5] sde5[4] sdd5[3] sdc5[2] sdb5[1]
      35120552832 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 64k chunk, algorithm 2 [10/9] [UUUUUUUUU_]

md1 : active raid1 sdj2[0]
      2097088 blocks [10/1] [U_________]

md0 : active raid1 sdj1[0]
      2490176 blocks [10/1] [U_________]

unused devices: <none>
```

Now, I'd like to be able to mount my raids.

I'll try to mount the raid md127 as it seems to be the biggest one (the one containing my data)

```
bash-4.3# mkdir /volume_restore
bash-4.3# mount /dev/md127 /volume_restore/
mount: unknown filesystem type 'LVM2_member'
```

I try to find some information about the Volume Group

```
bash-4.3# vgdisplay 
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               vg1000
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  2
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                1
  Open LV               0
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               32.71 TiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              8574353
  Alloc PE / Size       8574353 / 32.71 TiB
  Free  PE / Size       0 / 0   
  VG UUID               Mxjnuy-PmQl-3TBT-zUa2-kBj8-j3AO-PNibo3
```

There is a Volume Group

```
bash-4.3# lvdisplay 
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/vg1000/lv
  LV Name                lv
  VG Name                vg1000
  LV UUID                u1Ik6T-BQDC-ljKt-TocR-brIQ-5g6R-BR0JTv
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time , 
  LV Status              NOT available
  LV Size                32.71 TiB
  Current LE             8574353
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
```

And a logical Volume

A can't find the vg1000 in /dev/vg1000. I seems to be inactive. So I activate it doing:

```
bash-4.3# vgchange -ay
  1 logical volume(s) in volume group "vg1000" now active
```

Now I'm able to mount it!

```
mount /dev/vg1000/lv /volume_restore/
```

**@ this point make a backup !**

We'll now "merge the raids"

```
bash-4.3# cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : [linear] [raid0] [raid1] [raid10] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] 
md125 : active raid1 sda1[0] sdi1[8] sdh1[7] sdg1[6] sdf1[5] sde1[4] sdd1[3] sdc1[2] sdb1[1]
      2490176 blocks [10/9] [UUUUUUUUU_]

md126 : active raid1 sda2[0] sdi2[8] sdh2[7] sdg2[6] sdf2[5] sde2[4] sdd2[3] sdc2[2] sdb2[1]
      2097088 blocks [10/9] [UUUUUUUUU_]

md127 : active raid5 sda5[0] sdi5[8] sdh5[7] sdg5[6] sdf5[5] sde5[4] sdd5[3] sdc5[2] sdb5[1]
      35120552832 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 64k chunk, algorithm 2 [10/9] [UUUUUUUUU_]

md1 : active raid1 sdj2[0]
      2097088 blocks [10/1] [U_________]

md0 : active raid1 sdj1[0]
      2490176 blocks [10/1] [U_________]
```

md125 seems to be the old root partition of my former RAID . I'll try to propagate the md0 to all the disks

first stop /dev/md125

```
mdadm --stop /dev/md125
```

check that'is stopped

```
bash-4.3# cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : [linear] [raid0] [raid1] [raid10] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] 
md126 : active raid1 sda2[0] sdi2[8] sdh2[7] sdg2[6] sdf2[5] sde2[4] sdd2[3] sdc2[2] sdb2[1]
      2097088 blocks [10/9] [UUUUUUUUU_]

md127 : active raid5 sda5[0] sdi5[8] sdh5[7] sdg5[6] sdf5[5] sde5[4] sdd5[3] sdc5[2] sdb5[1]
      35120552832 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 64k chunk, algorithm 2 [10/9] [UUUUUUUUU_]

md1 : active raid1 sdj2[0]
      2097088 blocks [10/1] [U_________]

md0 : active raid1 sdj1[0]
      2490176 blocks [10/1] [U_________]
```

now add all the former partitions of your disks to the raid

```
bash-4.3# /sbin/mdadm --add /dev/md0 /dev/sda1 /dev/sdi1 /dev/sdh1 /dev/sdg1 /dev/sdf1 /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdb1
mdadm: added /dev/sda1
mdadm: added /dev/sdi1
mdadm: added /dev/sdh1
mdadm: added /dev/sdg1
mdadm: added /dev/sdf1
mdadm: added /dev/sdc1
mdadm: added /dev/sdb1
```

check if it worked

```
bash-4.3# cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : [linear] [raid0] [raid1] [raid10] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] 
md126 : active raid1 sda2[0] sdi2[8] sdh2[7] sdg2[6] sdf2[5] sde2[4] sdd2[3] sdc2[2] sdb2[1]
      2097088 blocks [10/9] [UUUUUUUUU_]

md127 : active raid5 sda5[0] sdi5[8] sdh5[7] sdg5[6] sdf5[5] sde5[4] sdd5[3] sdc5[2] sdb5[1]
      35120552832 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 64k chunk, algorithm 2 [10/9] [UUUUUUUUU_]

md1 : active raid1 sdj2[0]
      2097088 blocks [10/1] [U_________]

md0 : active raid1 sdb1[10](S) sdc1[11](S) sdf1[12](S) sdg1[13](S) sdh1[14](S) sdi1[15](S) sda1[16] sdj1[0]
      2490176 blocks [10/1] [U_________]
      [>....................]  recovery =  2.4% (60032/2490176) finish=3.3min speed=12006K/sec
```

You can do the same for md1

For you're data raid, you'll need to create the partition (in my case sdj5) on your "new disk".

I did it quite easily using parted on /dev/sda to know the propreties of the partition

```
rbash-4.3# parted /dev/sda
GNU Parted 3.2
Using /dev/sda
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) print                                                            
print
Model: WDC WD4000F9YZ-09N20 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 4001GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name  Flags
 1      131kB   2550MB  2550MB  ext4                  raid
 2      2550MB  4698MB  2147MB  linux-swap(v1)        raid
 5      4840MB  4001GB  3996GB                        raid
```

The created the same partition using parted /dev/sdj

```
bash-4.3# parted /dev/sdj
mkpart primary 4840MB 4001GB
set 1 raid on
Model: WDC WD4000F9YZ-09N20 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdj: 4001GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  2551MB  2550MB  ext4                  raid
 2      2551MB  4699MB  2147MB  linux-swap(v1)        raid
 3      4840MB  4001GB  3996GB                        raid
quit
```

At this time it created a partition n°3 but I don't mind.

I only need to add this partition to my raid doing:

```
bash-4.3# /sbin/mdadm --add /dev/md127 /dev/sdj3
```

You can then check if your raid is rebuilding with

```
bash-4.3# cat /proc/mdstat
```